# What database supports over a thousand fields and tables

Tags: nosql

I have a requirement to store several csv files with several fields in an database. This data does not need to be searchable but i need to query the data by Id. I will also need SQL to query the data so this may rule out many nosql options. Considering, each csv file is huge I will need to put each csv file in a separate table. i do not need to perform joins, subqueries or anything complicated - I just need to query by Id. Since the database will be getting hit hard with thousands of requests per hour horizontal scaling would be nice. Is there a database that can handle these requirements?

I have checked out MongoDB but it does not support sql. MongoDB would have been perfect if it supported basic sql.

Comment: "thousands of requests per hour" can be easily handled by any proper database (I'm excluding SQLite, MS Access and the likes) on very modest hardware. Also, "huge" files do not necessarily require to be stored in separate tables.

Comment: Ah sorry for misunderstanding. Each table will be hit up to 3000 times per hour. It will be serving a public api. We are currently using SQL Server and it is handling it well but we are approaching disk space and number of fields limits.

Comment: 3000 requests per hour is less than 1 request/second. One could do that with pencil and paper. Recent SQL Server versions should support petabyte-sized tables; are you exceeding that limit, or is it about the free SQL Server Express 10 GB limit?

Comment: @mustaccio Yes, we are using the express edition. The disk space is probably not much of an issue vs field limits. We can migrate to mysql to satisfy disk limits. But if we do that mysql has more strict field count limitations. Horizontal scaling is not an immediate issue either but it would be nice to have during traffic spikes.  Our immediate issue is satisfying field limitation. Each month we need to add a new field so we are approaching the limit in next year.

Comment: Re: "Each month we need to add a new field" -- I think you need to reconsider your data model. You will be better off in the long run designing your database properly instead of throwing hardware at a suboptimal solution and changing platforms every year.

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation would be for you to check out [**Cassandra**](http://cassandra.apache.org/).  In my experience, and based on the requirements you seem to have, it seems like it would be a good fit.

It appears to me that you have essentially have these requirements:

**(1)** Key-value storage (look up data based on ID)

**(2)** No need for `JOIN` or sub-`SELECT`

**(3)** Need for a SQL-like language

**(4)** Horizontal scalability

As for **(1)**, Cassandra will hash the primary key (in your case you can use a single column `id` as your primary key) and which node in the cluster stores the data, and the Cassandra internals ensure look up by primary key is very fast.  Cassandra doesn't support `JOIN` as in **(2)**, but you appear to be OK with that.

Since you are essentially doing key-value lookups, I'm actually not sure why you need an SQL language.  Perhaps you are wanting to not only look up data by primary key, but also perform aggregations and use `GROUP BY`?  In this case, Cassandra won't work, but if you only need a simple SQL language to retrieve data as per **(3)**, Cassandra has **[CQL](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cqlIntro.html)**, which may serve your needs.

Horizontal scalability is built right in to Cassandra, covering **(4)**.

All that being said, Cassandra isn't a silver bullet.  It's a great technology for certain applications, and it sounds like it fits you needs.  Still, if you want aggregations, or if you want to query for multiple primary keys in a single query (e.g. `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (...)`), then you may run in to some issues.

Now, if you can let go of constraint **(4)**, I'd 100% be promoting PostgreSQL.  You stated the database will be getting hit with thousands of requests per hour, but that's nothing for a database like [**PostgreSQL**](http://www.postgresql.org), if your queries are only individual primary key lookups, and you aren't trying to transfer large amounts of data in those queries.

Best of luck!  If you provide more info based on my feedback, perhaps the community here can help you narrow down your selection even more.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (...)" will be needed but group by or aggregations are not. Can Postgresql satisfy 1000+ fields requirement? I heard they support up to 1600 fields depending on field types. Some tables may have 2000 fields and some fields will be large varchar(max). Cassandra, looks very promising Ill need to do more research on them but I will need SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (...) queries.

Comment: @Luke101: With Postgres you might want to consider `hstore` (a key/value data type) instead of 2000 columns.

Comment: So, if you want to access multiple primary keys with an `IN()` query in Cassandra, it's what's called a multi-get, and it leads to cases where you may need to pull data from every single node in your cluster to serve the query.  In such cases, I would recommend, rather than performing an `IN()` query for X ids, perform X asynchronous queries for one id at a time, and reconstruct your answer on the client-side application.  Just my two cents.